# JSON parsing in JavaScript for PhoneGap application

Tags: json, dictionary, cordova, marker

I want to parse an array of latitudes and longitudes from JSON. I want to mark those points in map with different markers in phone-gap Android using JavaScript. Please help me by providing me a link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [json parsing using javascript for phonegap android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163394/json-parsing-using-javascript-for-phonegap-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1

Comment: when i run the code from above link ,i could see only the white spaces

Comment: You could be coming across the fairly new PhoneGap white-list feature. In Android, this means adding any remote hosts you reference files from (scripts, images, etc) in the re/xml/phonegap.xml file. this needs an entry (or wildcard) for every external host you need to call files from. i.e.: `<access origin="http://*.phonegap.com"/>`